# How do I make is so the entered number is multiplied by the slider number

Tags: xcode, swift

I've created an iOS app that multiplies the entered number by the number that's in the slider. Please forgive my ignorance, but as you can tell, I'm just learning. The section where the user enters their number is the multiplier text field. I tried to convert it to an "`Int`" but it's not working.

**This is the error:**

> Binary operator '*' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Float' and
>   'Int?'

**Here's the code:**

```
@IBOutlet weak var multiplier: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var sliderLabel: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var sliderValue: UISlider!

@IBAction func sliderController(sender: AnyObject) {

    table.reloadData()

    sliderLabel.text = "\(sliderValue.value)"

}

@IBOutlet weak var table: UITableView!

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return 20

}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var numbers = multiplier.text.toInt()

    let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")

    let timesTable = Int(sliderValue.value * numbers)

    cell.textLabel?.text = String(timesTable * (indexPath.row + 1))

    return cell

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats because your slider.value returns a Float. You are trying to convert the result of it but you need to convert just the slider.value to Int to multiply it by numbers which is an Int. Try like this:

Note: As mentioned by Josh you need also to unwrap toInt() optional result. You can use "??" nil coalescing operator to return 0 in case of invalid input.

```
 let numbers = multiplier.text.toInt() ?? 0 

 let timesTable = Int(sliderValue.value) * numbers
```

Comment: I changed it to that and unwrapped the it with the "var numbers = multiplier.text.toInt()!. This allows me to run the code, but it errors again with "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXCI386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)"

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind, toInt() returns an optional so you will need to unwrap it when attempting to multiply it by sliderValue.

Comment: let numbers = multiplier.text.toInt() ?? 0

Comment: let numbers = multiplier.text.toInt()! if you know for a fact that multiplier.text will contain valid input. If invalid input may be entered such as "hello" which will return null, use optional chaining to first check if null was not returned

Comment: ?? will return 0 in case of nil. Take a look at nil coalescing operator